# in python pandas, how to unpack the lists in a column?

Tags: python, pandas

i have a  python data frame, which contains 3 columns:

```
['date', 'country', 'dollar']
```

country is a string, which normally looks like 'singapore' 'ukraine' etc

sometimes, country column's item is a list of countries, separated by |, such as

```
'US|UK|Germany'
```

the corresponding row will be:

```
20140101, 'US|UK|Germany', 123456
```

what i want is to 'unpack' the country column, and makes it strictly 1 country per row, the above row should be unpacked into 3 rows:

```
20140101, 'US', 123456
20140101, 'UK', 123456
20140101, 'Germany', 123456
```

is there any neat way to do this?

thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Use [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html)

```
df = df.explode('country')
```

Answer (score 7):

This solution will change the order of you columns, which I think is fine in most cases. You can replace `dict` with `OrderedDict` if you want to preserve the column orders.

```
In [31]:
print DF
       date        country  dollar
0  20140101  US|UK|Germany  123456
1  20140101  US|UK|Germany  123457

[2 rows x 3 columns]
In [32]:

DF.country=DF.country.apply(lambda x: x.split('|'))
print DF
       date            country  dollar
0  20140101  [US, UK, Germany]  123456
1  20140101  [US, UK, Germany]  123457

[2 rows x 3 columns]
In [33]:

print pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(DF.columns,DF.ix[i]))) for i in range(len(DF))])
   country      date  dollar
0       US  20140101  123456
1       UK  20140101  123456
2  Germany  20140101  123456
0       US  20140101  123457
1       UK  20140101  123457
2  Germany  20140101  123457

[6 rows x 3 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
a = [20140101, 'US|UK|Germany', 123456]
[[a[0], country, a[2]] for country in a[1].split('|')]


[[20140101, 'US', 123456],
 [20140101, 'UK', 123456],
 [20140101, 'Germany', 123456]]
```

Comment: The answer was asking about Pandas, not pure python.